# Delete from table in sql with condition

Tags: sql, sql-delete

I have data in the table `tab_asg` like :

```
start_date  end_date       person_id
------------------------------------
19-08-2012  18-08-2012       1
19-08-2012  16-08-2016       1
17-08-2016  31-12-4712       1
```

I want to delete first row from this table `where end_date < start_date` and 1st two rows start_date is same.

```
delete from tab_asg
where end_date <start_date;
```

I have added the condition `end_date < start_date` to my query. How can I add the 2nd condition that is 1st two rows start_date is same?

Comment: `I want to delete first row from this table` ... you need to specify an ordering for the notion of "first row" to make any sense.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - Thanks but what i have the given the condition which row i need to delete which will always be the frst row

Comment: You want to delete all rows where `end_date < start_date`.??<br>What is the second condition???

Comment: There is no first row without you specifying an order.

Comment: @divya.trehan573 Show expected result please.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way to do this is to

First add primary key column Id to the table and fill it with unique ids. In SQL Server it would look something like this:

```
ALTER TABLE tab_asg
ADD Id int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1)
```

Then delete appropriate rows from the table

```
DELETE FROM tab_asg 
WHERE Id IN 
(SELECT ta1.Id FROM tab_asg ta1 LEFT JOIN tab_asg ta2 
ON ta1.person_id = ta2.person_id AND ta1.start_date = ta2.start_date 
AND ta1.end_date < ta2.end_date WHERE ta2.end_date IS NOT NULL)
```